# make hover popup opaque in react css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a react app where on long texts when I hover my cursor,it shows a popup like this,but somehow its transparent and the table lines are also visible here.

[image]

As you can see,In between the lines I can see the white lines which are actually table borders.

How can i fix it?

Here's my code:

```
<Table.Cell data-title={message.message}>
                  {this.truncate(message.message, 50)}
                </Table.Cell>
```

This is the table row inside the component.

Now here's the css:

```
[data-title] {
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: help;
}
  
[data-title]:hover::before {
    content: attr(data-title);
  opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
  margin-top:33px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
  width:300px;
    white-space: wrap;
}
[data-title]:hover::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: 8px;
    border: 8px solid transparent;  
    border-bottom: 8px solid #000;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Give more z-index to the popup than the table.

Comment: where to add in the above css?

Comment: You need to add less z-index for table, row, cell and more z-index for popup. Above css just handles the cell.

Comment: the above css is for the popup when hovered over cell

Comment: @rudeTool Could you add simple sample of your code in codesandbox?

Comment: sure,just a min

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-leakey-q6hef

Here's the link @MajidM.check the cells in message column,they are transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give `z-index` to `[data-title]:hover::before`
for example:

```
[data-title]:hover::before {
    content: attr(data-title);
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:33px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    width:300px;
    white-space: wrap;
    z-index: 9;
}
```